# FreeRDP code sample

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, remote-desktop, rdp

I've been through tough times trying figuring out how to create Remote Desktop connection client using FreeRDP (https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP).

Could anyone provide basic example how to connect to remote PC using their API with machine IP address, 
Username and Password for any platform?

I was looking through their WIKI and API reference but it's looks overcomplicated to me.

From the beginning I planned to use [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) in Microsoft Xamarin project for cross platform devices but
now it seems to me that I'll have to precompile it both for Android and iOS.